# Enumerator display read from structures?

Tags: c++, file-io, struct, enumerators

I have this enumerator that you read from a structure it says enum {PASSING, FAILING}
it's meant to display failing or passing .. it does that however i get (status Failing0)(status PASSING1) as a final out put,... anyone knows why the 1 and the 0 are showing up? any tips on what to do?

```
 if(info[i].average <70)
{
info[i].status = FAILING;
}
else
{
 info[i].status = PASSING;
}
switch(info[i].status)
{
 case FAILING: cout << "Status FAILING";// <<endl; 
 break;
 case PASSING: cout << "Status PASSING";// <<endl;

}
cout << info[i].status <<endl;
```

Comment: because you print it in this line `cout << info[i].status <<endl;`

Comment: because i print out that line else how do i print fail or passing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a map:

```
#include <string>
#include <map>

enum TheEnumType { PASSING, FAILING };

std::map<TheEnumType, std::string> enum_names =  { { PASSING, "Passing" },
                                                   { FAILING, "Failing" } };

std::cout << enum_names[info[i].status];
```